# In JavaScript, how can I extract several values at once?

Tags: javascript

In the example below, I want to extract "apple", "orange" and "kiwi" at once, and show them in the console. I'm not sure how to write `arrayExample[0 && 1 && 2]`.

```
arrayExample = ["apple", "orange", "kiwi", "banana", "melon", "peach"];

console.log(arrayExample[0 && 1 && 2]);
```

Comment: console.log accepts multiple arguments, so console.log(arrayExample[0], arrayExample[1], ...) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You want to append the elements of the array into a string.

In Javascript you can append strings (and your array elements are strings) with the `+` operator.

Something along the lines of:

```
console.log(arrayExample[0] + " " + arrayExample[1] + " " + arrayExample[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.slice` is what you're looking for.

```
arrayExample = ["apple", "orange", "kiwi", "banana", "melon", "peach"];

console.log(arrayExample.slice(0, 3));
```

Check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

BTW `0 && 1 && 2 === 0` ;-)